# AngularJS Getting data from asynchronous call

Tags: angularjs, callback, http-get

I have multiple scripts with the same object which uses the jQuery.GET to fetch some data.

**crawler1.js** ->

```
var crawlers = crawlers || {};

crawlers.Crawler1 = {
  getData : function(cb) {
    $.get('linkToSite').done(function(data){
        cb(data);
      }).fail(function(err){
          cb(false);
      });
  }
};
```

In **app.js** I have my "MainController" which needs to just receive this data.

So far I have this:

```
var tempData;
crawlers['Crawler1 '].getData (function(data) {
    tempData = data;
});

console.log(tempData);//This is UNDEFINED
```

Now I know this returns "undefined" because I'm using Asynchronous call and you don't know when it will return the data.

**Is there a way to get this data out of the callback ?**

I need it out of it and **not** something like this:

```
crawlers['Crawler1 '].getData (function(data) {
    tempFunc(data);
});
tempFunc(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: AngularJS has [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Can you add a callback to the getData() function, so: getData(data => tempData = data, () => console.log(tempData)); like you would in say, React?